# WPF ToolTip does not show part of the text

Tags: wpf, tooltip

ToolTip reserves space for text but does not display it.

So displayed on Win XP and Win 7

[image]

Should be like that

[image]

ToolTip style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Static common:WPFColors.NESTED_FORMS_BORDER_BRUSH}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static settings:UIGeneratorBackgrounds.DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_WPF_BRUSH}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static common:WPFColors.DESCRIPTION_FOREGROUND_BRUSH}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}},Path=(TextBlock.TextWrapping),Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

XAML:

```
<grid:GridCell ToolTip="{Binding Path=PaymentTypeToolTip,Mode=OneWay}">...</grid:GridCell>
```

But everything works if I write like this:

```
<grid:GridCell>
    <grid:GridCell.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=PaymentTypeToolTip,Mode=OneWay}">
            <ToolTip.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
                </Style>
            </ToolTip.Style>
        </ToolTip>
    </grid:GridCell.ToolTip>
    ...
</grid:GridCell>
```

This error appeared only on WinXP and Win7, only on one window, on one control, which works fine in other places.

Why could this be? Writing style to ToolTip and TextWrapping = NoWrap is not an option everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` instead of `FindAncestor`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} return TextBlock, not ToolTip